# Как расположить кнопку с новой строки Telegram bot на Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

[image: Кнопки идут в строчку]

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("О нас")
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Сотрудничество")
btn3= types.KeyboardButton("Как улучшить бота?")
markup.add(btn1, btn2,btn3)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, {0.first_name}! Добро пожаловать в нашу семью".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("О нас")
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Сотрудничество")
btn3= types.KeyboardButton("Как улучшить бота?")
markup.add(btn1).add(btn2).add(btn3)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, {0.first_name}! Добро пожаловать в нашу семью".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!